# failure of catkin_make_isolated on FreeBSD

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to install ROS Kinetic on FreeBSD 12.1 (at my peril).

I'm following the 'from source' instructions at:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source

I am performing step 2.1.3 (Building the catkin workspace), which directs invoking `catkin_make_isolated` as follows:
`./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

I get the following output:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
...
==> make -j4 -l4 in '$PATH/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
...
<== Failed to process package 'catkin':
Command '['make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

This seems to be due to FreeBSD `make` not having the loading average flag `-l`.

I have tried both setting the `MAKEFLAGS` and `ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS` environment variables to avoid setting the `-l` flag.  E.g., `set ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS='-j4'`.

The result is that it sends a flag `-pn` to `make`, as follows:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
...
==> make -j4 in '$PATH/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
...
<== Failed to process package 'catkin':
Command '['make', '-pn']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Interestingly, it appears that it's invoking `make -j4`, but then says that the actual flag sent to `make` is `-pn`.

I have also attempted to set the flags when invoking `catkin_make_isolated`, but get the same result (with `-pn`).  For example:
`./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -j4`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341938/failure-of-catkin_make_isolated-on-freebsd/) by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found my answer by posting a similar question elsewhere:

https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/1047

In short, FreeBSD `make` is not the same as GNU `make` and has different flags.  Installing GNU `make` doesn't immediately fix the problem because the binary name is `gmake` in FreeBSD, but `make` is hardcoded into catkin's `builder.py` script.

The workaround (modifying the `builder.py` script) is documented in the github thread cited above.

EDIT:  The workaround to use `gmake` on FreeBSD has been pulled into Catkin, which now supports the `--use-gmake` argument (https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1051)

---

Originally posted by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) with karma: 111 on 2020-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0